# Is there a way to restore the pages, blogs and widgets I have removed from Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-pages

Is there a way to restore the pages, blogs and widgets I have removed from Magento 2? I want the contact us, cookies and other pages back. Do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there are no way to restore deleted item. You can use third party extension for achieve this.

Amasty admin action log extension support restore feature [ I am not part of Amasty or it's module marketing].